# Populating a 2D list with two different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to created a 2D list, with 2 positions in each list but with two different variables.

This is for a school project, the name is meant to come first and then a homework mark which I would like to insert later. This is my code so far:

```
student_group_list = ['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', 'EDWARDS Elizabeth', 'GREGORY Isabella', 'Hendley-Jones Annabel', 'LIS Natalia', 'MANNING Sophie', 'RATCLIFFE George', 'BELLAMY Jacob', 'BOUGHTON Grace', 'GARNETT Archie', 'Maruta Kudzai', 'DAVELIS Alexander', 'DENMAN David', 'JENKIN Jonathan', 'LISTER Thomas', 'CLOWES Edward', 'OGG Holly', 'PUGH Billy']

hwklist = [[student_group_list[i] for j in range(2)] for i in range(len(student_group_list))]
print (hwklist)
```

I'm want it to output

```
[['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', ''], ['EDWARDS Elizabeth', '']...
```

but right now I'm getting

```
[['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', 'BERRY-SMITH Finlay'], ['EDWARDS Elizabeth', 'EDWARDS Elizabeth']...
```

I want to know if there is any way that I can insert variable 1 into the index  0, and variable 2 into the index 1 when the 2D list is created. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the same way you declare the `student_group_list`, manually:

```
result = [[student, ''] for student in student_group_list]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['BERRY-SMITH Finlay', ''], ['EDWARDS Elizabeth', ''], ['GREGORY Isabella', ''], ['Hendley-Jones Annabel', ''], ['LIS Natalia', ''], ['MANNING Sophie', ''], ['RATCLIFFE George', ''], ['BELLAMY Jacob', ''], ['BOUGHTON Grace', ''], ['GARNETT Archie', ''], ['Maruta Kudzai', ''], ['DAVELIS Alexander', ''], ['DENMAN David', ''], ['JENKIN Jonathan', ''], ['LISTER Thomas', ''], ['CLOWES Edward', ''], ['OGG Holly', ''], ['PUGH Billy', '']]
```

But if the names of the students are unique, I suggest you use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of a nested list. With the names as keys and the marks as values.